# Cakephp make a request in the finder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Help write and execute this query in finder cakephp 3.5.10

After, I need to group the result by user_id.

Below is the table structure, for the convenience of the from Adminer.

```
    select user_id, GRP, MIN(time) as Start, MAX(time) as End
      from (select user_id, time,
           @grp:=@grp+if(time>@prev+interval 30 minute,1,0) as GRP,
           @prev:=time
      from user_log, (select @prev:=NULL, @grp:=1) X
     order by time) A
     group by GRP
```

Details:

[image: Data]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a query writing service, you need to show some effort, what you've done and your code... Start reading here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Answer (score -3):

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$sql = 'select user_id, GRP, MIN(time) as Start, MAX(time) as End from (select user_id, time, @grp:=@grp+if(time>@prev+interval 30 minute,1,0) as GRP,@prev:=time from user_log, (select @prev:=NULL, @grp:=1) X order by time) A group by GRP';

$stmt = $conn->execute($sql);

$user = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Comment: How can I add conditions?

Comment: you can directly copy and past sql query in $sql string and try.

Comment: This is bypassing the query builder completely, which is a bad idea.